# Convex hull in a discrete space

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, computational-geometry, convex-hulls

I know some algorithms which compute the convex hull in a continuous space.
Are there efficient algorithms to compute it in a discrete domain?
For example in 3D discrete space, given the blue points, we want the convex hull including the green points.

[image]

Comment: The figure doesn't look 3d

Comment: Also, there's a Computer Science SE and a Theoretical Computer Science SE. I'm wondering if this question would be more appropriate there...

Comment: This fugure's points are plotted on the plane v1 + v2 + v3 = 7. So, it's a pseudo 3D.

Comment: Could you show me the URL for Computer Science forum?

Comment: This is for all questions: https://cs.stackexchange.com/. This is for only research level questions: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/34621/jkabrg

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

There is a notion called the "orthogonal convex hull," or
the "digital convex hull," which may be what you seek.
For example, in this paper,

> Karmakar, Nilanjana, and Arindam Biswas. "Construction of 3D Orthogonal Convex Hull of a Digital Object." In *International Workshop on Combinatorial Image Analysis*, pp. 125-142. Springer, Cham, 2015.
>   [Springer link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-26145-4_10).

the authors define it this way:
"Orthogonal convex hull of a digital object in 3D domain is defined as the minimum volume orthogonal polyhedron enclosing the object such that its intersection with an axis-parallel face plane is either empty or a collection of projection-disjoint convex polygons."

---

[image]

---

Here's another image, specifically in 2D:

---

[image]

          

<sup>Image from [P. Bhowmick's slides (PDF)](https://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/~pb/convex-hull-talk-nit-dgp-2014a.pdf).</sup>

---

> A. Biswas, P. Bhowmick, M. Sarkar, B. B. Bhattacharya, "A
>   linear-time combinatorial algorithm to find the orthogonal hull of
>   an object on the digital plane," *Information Sciences*, 216,
>   pp. 176–195, 2012.
>   [Elsevier link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025512004100).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems only for 3D, right?

Comment: @Smith: No, the notion has been explored in 2D, 3D, and higher dimensions. I added a citation specifically for 2D.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Smith: And similar notions hold for the triangular lattice in your example.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the most general notion that would be relevant here is geodesic convexity, which can be defined in any graph. (See, for example, the book [*Geodesic Convexity in Graphs* by Ignasio M. Pelayo](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-8699-2).)

Here, given any graph $G$, a set of vertices $S \subseteq V(G)$ is convex if, for any vertices $u,v \in S$, every shortest $u,v$-path stays in $S$. As usual, the convex hull of a set is the smallest convex set containing it, or equivalently the intersection of all convex sets containing it. So, in your example, a convex set containing all the blue points would also have to contain the green ones, due to the geodesics below:

[image]

As suggested by the book I cited above, we can compute the convex hull in a graph by repeated use of breadth-first search. Pick a starting vertex $s \in S$, and do a breadth-first search from $s$ until you reach every vertex of $S$; every vertex on a shortest path to those must be added to $S$. Repeat this, not just for every vertex in $S$, but also for every vertex found along the way.